# What would be the fastapi-asyncpg session object equivalent to SQLalchemy Session

Tags: redis, sqlalchemy, fastapi, asyncpg

I have an fastapi application where redis will be used for cache. I am using a package called fastapi_redis_cache. Currently we are moving from SQLalchemy to asyncpg while connecting with the redis what would be the DB session for asyncpg, So that can be excluded from creating keys

Tried with Connectionpool but that was not work

https://github.com/a-luna/fastapi-redis-cache

```py
from fastapi_redis_cache import FastApiRedisCache, cache
import os
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

@app.on_event("startup")
def startup():
    redis_cache = FastApiRedisCache()
    redis_cache.init(
        host_url=os.environ.get("REDIS_URL", REDIS_URL),
        prefix="myapi-cache",
        response_header="X-MyAPI-Cache",
        ignore_arg_types=[Request, Response, Session]
```

Comment: How do you use `asyncpg`, how is it injected into your API routes? That will determine what you should ignore in `fastapi_redis_cache`.

Comment: We are using dependency injection like `current_user: um_models.User = Depends(ua.get_current_user)`